# Create a filtered copy of a .tar.gz file with unwanted files removed

Tags: command-line, tar

What is the Linux shell equivalent of this Windows shell batch file command?

```
tar czf b.tgz --exclude="dontwant.tgz" @a.tgz
```

What I need to achieve:

- `a.tgz` has many files including `dontwant.tgz`.
- I want to create `b.tgz` such that it has all files in `a.tgz` except `dontwant.tgz`.

Comment: Oh, thanks! That `@a.tgz` has an interesting meaning! I wouldn't have thought this to be a functionality of any shell. Wow!

Comment: Read `man tar` and `info tar`.

Comment: @waltinator it depends whether you're using GNU tar or BSD tar. Only BSD tar includes support for `@tarball`

Comment: Perhaps add more information about which version of `tar` you're using etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Linux distro if there is a `bsdtar` (just type it into a terminal) and use this instead of `tar`. First one is FreeBSD (and therefore "macOS") Tar *with* your required "@" option, second one GNU Tar *without* it. My current system (Slackware based) has both.

Keep in mind that "tar" is a file format that can be handled by different programs with different features (though it started out some decades ago in UNIX as single program).